# Why is 8086 memory divided into odd and even banks?

Tags: memory, cpu-word, x86-16, memory-alignment

1. What is the benefit of dividing memory into banks ?
2. How can 8086 access a word in a single access using this scheme but can't do so using a single memory chip ? ( AFAIK processors usually access memory in chunks instead of single bytes anyways so can't understand why it can't just access a word in single access in case of a single memory chip)
3. Is the division of memory into banks a physical one or logical one ?
4. How are the data lines connected to the memory in case of even and odd banks and in case of single chip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 8086 has 20-bit addressing model for memory access. Each address represents a single byte - however, the natural word size of 8086 is 2 bytes, so you need a way to read two bytes at the same time - hence, two banks. The main benefit here is simplification - you need no memory controller, the CPU directly accessed data from the 8-bit modules.
2. Modern processors access memory in chunks, yes. This wasn't the case back when 8086 was designed - the CPU was slow enough that the memory latency didn't matter. If you had an 8-bit memory module, it gave you 8 bits, and that's it. The later 32-bit 486 could use either four 8-bit banks, or a "non-banked" 32-bit module configuration, and exploited both onboard memory cache and instruction pipelining - the 8086 had neither.
3. Both physical and logical.
4. One bank has all the odd bytes, the other all the even bytes in a word.

There's a few other complexities involved, but basically, the point is quite simple - the technologies you assume didn't exist yet, or were impractically expensive. As transistors got cheaper over time, we got more and more goodies.

Comment: Okay that clears a little but how does 8086 actually access a word in a single access , say it wants bytes at 20000H and 20001H, then address bus will have 20000H but how then does 20001H get accessed in the same cycle ? Also can you elaborate a little on point 3 ? And finally a little unrelated but how does a modern processor access memory in chunks then ?  Sorry if the questions are too silly

Comment: @nino The data bus is 16-bit wide. One bank is mapped to bits 0-7, the other to 8-15. The address is the same for both banks in the 16-bit scenario (only A1-19 bits are used for addressing, BHE and BLE select the bank), so when you read memory from 20000h, you get both bytes at the same time. What would you want to know about 3? A modern system has a much wider data bus, and the memory modules have their own logic that allows them to quickly send a few rows in sequence, but the full description is very easy to find and too long to fit in the margins here :)

Comment: so both banks will receive A1-19 i.e (0010 0000 0000 0000 000) in binary if we consider 20000H again and the special pins will decide which banks are enabled for access , but  i didn't really understand "the address is same for both the banks in 16-bit scenario" , we are using 19 bits no ? , about point 3 i did not understand how is the division both physical and logical

Comment: @nino Yes, exactly. 19 bits are used for addressing, 16 bits for the data. Physically, you have two separate modules, each with their own 8 bits of data bus. Logically, one of the modules contains all the odd addresses, and one all the even addresses. That's why I wanted to know what you mean by physical vs. logical :)

Comment: However, the 8088 variant (the one used in the original IBM PC) had an 8-bit data bus instead of a 16-bit bus. This allowed the computer maker to use less expensive and more widely available 8-bit support components in the motherboard. Internally, the 8088 mapped a 16-bit wide operation into two consecutive 8-bit wide operations. So you got a slightly cheaper computer in exchange for a slight drop in performance when accessing information outside the processor.